# Java Script return value from fetch isn't correct

Tags: javascript

I've been solving this quiz for day and still can't get the correct answer here's the code

```
function thisIsSyncFunction() {
    let result = 0;
 
    fetch('https://codequiz.azurewebsites.net/data').then(res => res.json()).then((response) =>    {
        result = response.data;
    });
    return result;
}
 
const number1 = thisIsSyncFunction()
const calculation = number1 * 10;
console.log(calculation);
```

why the number1 still return value of 0 but If I change result to other number It's return correctly?

Comment: Fetch is asynchronous. Your function returns before your `then` runs.

Comment: Return the result in the last .then

Comment: After I return the result in the last .then  It's show Nan (expect "100") why is that ?